# How to use Intel® Integrated Native Developer Experience to develop Android native app's.

Tags: android, cross-platform, intel, intelinde

Intel has new a beta release of Intel's cross-platform development suite to quickly & easily create applications targeting Android* and Windows* devices with native performance.

I have read about that from here [intel Integrated Native Developer Experience](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-inde) and also downloaded one set up from [Intel® INDE Opt-in Free Trial](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-free-program). But I didn't find the complete instructions how to use that setup with the current Android SDK or How to develop applications using this.

If anyone know about it please guide me.

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/introduction-to-cross-platform-application-development-using-appmobi-xdk I guess this is the android section for Intel Cross Platform Development, I hope that will help you

Comment: @Aaღirkhan I think INDE is different from XDK.

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/blogs/2014/01/02/developing-android-apps-using-intel-xdk-and-threejs

Comment: The Intel(R) XDK is indeed something different. The XDK is a HTML5 cross development tool environment while Intel INDE providing tools for native development in C++ or Java in the case of Android.

Comment: @AlexanderWeggerle do you know how we can start work with INDE ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Intel INDE provides different tools for different development scenarios. It's still in beta and so there might be changes later to what I write.
Start with the "environment setup" which setups Android ADT, Android NDK and Visual Studio plugins for Android development.

The other tools are mostly for specific use cases. So to decide with which tool you want to continue depends on your needs:

Performance

- Compiler: Optimized compiler for x86 targets
- Compute Code Builder: Helps with developing OpenCL kernels
- Threading: This is "Threading Building Blocks", a C++ template library for task parallelism.

Graphics/Media

- GPA Frame Analyzer: Captures an OpenGL or DirectX frame to analyze it. For example you see all draw calls, Shader code and depending on the GPU also performance information
- GPA Frame Debugger: Helps you fixing issues in a recorded OpenGL frame
- GPA Platform Analyzer: Helps to understand the correlation between CPU and GPU by doing API tracing
- GPA System Analyzer: Showing real time performance metrics about CPU and GPU usage for Android and Windows devices. There are also so called state overwrites that are allowing real time experiments with the graphics of your app like reducing the size of all textures to 1x1. You need an x86 based target.
- Media: Optimized libraries mainly for audio and video.

BTW: I'm working for Intel.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding INDE Media Pack for Android there is a set of tutorials:

4 basic tutorials:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials

2 tutorials about game capturing in Unity based games:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials-video-capturing-for-unity3d-applications

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials-advanced-video-capturing-for-unity3d